# how to get last occurance of element m in array n

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, if-statement

I just started with programming and I am just trying to access the only last position of element m in array n.The code given below provide the all positions of element m.

```
 var n = [];
        while (true) {
            let input = prompt("enter number to array");
            if (input == null || input == "c") {
                break;
            }
            n.push(Number(input));
            console.log(n);
        }
        var m = prompt("enter number to be match");
        console.log(m)
        for (var i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
            if (n[i] == m) {
                console.log(i);
            }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over the array in the opposite direction-- note the new way the `for` loop is constructed:

```js
var n = [];
while (true) {
    let input = prompt("enter number to array");
    if (input == null || input == "c") {
        break;
    }
    n.push(Number(input));
    console.log(n);
}
var m = prompt("enter number to be match");
console.log(m)
for (var i = n.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (n[i] == m) {
        console.log(i);
    } 
}
```

**NOTE:**

While my solution shows how to alter your existing approach to achieve the desired result, please note that [Yousaf's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62539469/how-to-get-last-occurance-of-element-m-in-array-n/#62539526) is a much cleaner implementation; if you want to write concise code, then I would recommend leveraging that approach.

Comment: While my solution shows how to alter your existing approach to achieve the desired result, please not that @Yousaf 's solution is a much cleaner implementation; if you want to write concise code, then I would recommend leveraging that approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could use built-in [Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf) function to get the last index.

The `.lastIndexOf()` method returns the last index at which a given element can be found in the array, or -1 if it is not present. This function searches the array in reverse order, i.e. from last index towards the first index of the array.

```
n.lastIndexOf(m);
```

```js
var n = [];
while (true) {
  let input = prompt("enter number to array");
  if (input == null || input == "c") {
    break;
  }
  
  n.push(Number(input));
}

var m = Number(prompt("enter number to be match"));
console.log(n.lastIndexOf(m));
```

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the programming community :)

It's actually pretty easy. You can use `Array.prototype.lastIndexOf()` to retrieve the index of last occurence of an element.

I must add that you should probably check for error cases, for instance, if the user enters something which is not an integer. But for simplicity's sake, I'll just paste what you're looking for without the error checks

```
let n = [];

while (true) {
  const input = prompt('enter number to array');
  if (!input || input === 'c') {
    break;
  } else {
    n.push(Number(input));
    console.log(n);
  }
}

const m = Number(prompt('enter number to be match'));
console.log(m);
const lastIndexOfElement = n.lastIndexOf(m);
if (lastIndexOfElement < 0) {
  console.log(`element ${m} could not be found`);
} else {
  console.log(
    `the last occurence of ${m} can be found at position ${lastIndexOfElement}`
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `n.indexOf(m)` ( https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp ) to get the index (i). Do note, the indexof can be negative, if it's negative then its not in the array.